# How to have \n when stringifying JSON?

Tags: node.js, json, stringify

I am using gh API to get package and lock files of npm from a project. This gives us encoded data. Data is presentable after decoding and parsing the data. After parsing and updating the data, I need to send the changes to github using API. To do that I need to stringify and encode the data again. Now the problem is, when I stringify the data it becomes a string in one line. To resolve this issue I need to have `\n` in the string. I have got no idea how.

I want the data to look like this :

`"{\n  \"name\": \"test-1\",\n  \"version\": \"1.0.0\",\n  \"description\": \"\",\n  \"main\": \"index.js\",\n  \"scripts\": {\n    \"test\": \"echo \\\"Error: no test specified\\\" && exit 1\"\n  },\n  \"keywords\": [],\n  \"author\": \"\",\n  \"license\": \"ISC\",\n  \"dependencies\": {\n    \"axios\": \"^0.15.2\",\n    \"bluebird\": \"^2.0.7\",\n    \"body-parser\": \"^1.8.3\",\n    \"express\": \"^2.4.5\",\n    \"istanbul\": \"^0.1.31\",\n    \"mongoose\": \"^4.5.8\"\n  }\n}\n"`

But stringifying data gives me this :

`{"name":"test-1","version":"1.0.0","description":"","main":"index.js","scripts":{"test":"echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"},"keywords":[],"author":"","license":"ISC","dependencies":{"axios":"^0.15.2","bluebird":"^2.0.7","body-parser":"^1.8.3","express":"^2.4.5","istanbul":"^0.1.31","mongoose":"^4.5.8"}}`

Comment: try JSON.stringify(yourJSON, null, 2);

Answer (score 1):

You can add spaces in [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function. `JSON.stringify` takes 3 parameters: data, replacer function, spaces respectively.

```
JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
```